# leastsq() got multiple values for argument 'x0' error in the scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to input some starting guessing estimates in 
the `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` function.
According to [this link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)
and
 [another link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy.optimize.least_squares)

I should defind them in the x0, however I tried in different ways and I get the following error. *(Note: without the x0 argument, it works fine)*

TypeError: leastsq() got multiple values for argument 'x0'.

I provide below a reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import scipy.optimize
iris = load_iris()
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[ iris['target'], iris['data']],  columns=  ['target'] + iris['feature_names'] )

def formula_nls(data, pot, sp):
    return pot * np.tanh(data1.iloc[:,2] * sp / 2)

scipy.optimize.curve_fit(f = formula_nls, xdata= data1.iloc[:,1:],
                                                ydata= data1.iloc[:,0], method = 'lm',
                                             sigma = 1/data1.iloc[:,1], absolute_sigma=False,
                                                x0  = np.ndarray([ 1, 2]))
```

Maybe it is something simple that I am missing.
Thanks

Comment: It's `np.array` not `np.ndarray`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use argument`x0` when docs of `curve_fit` say:

> p0 : None, scalar, or N-length sequence, optional
>
> Initial guess for the parameters. If None, then the initial values will all be 1 (if the number of parameters for the function can be determined using introspection, otherwise a ValueError is raised).

This differs from the API in minimize and least_squares, e.g. for the latter:

> x0 : array_like with shape (n,) or float
>
> Initial guess on independent variables. If float, it will be treated as a 1-d array with one element.

And yes, internally in `curve_fit`, your given `p0` [becomes](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.0.0/scipy/optimize/minpack.py#L742) the `x0` in `least_squares`:

```
res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
```

As `x0` is not an argument for `curve_fit` i expect it to be treated as argument used for:

> kwargs
>
> Keyword arguments passed to leastsq for method='lm' or least_squares otherwise.

which means it will be passed to `leastsq` as `x0`, together with the `x0` coming from the call from `curve_fit`!

Something like this:

```
def fun(x0, **kwargs):
    return 1

print(fun(1))
# 1
print(fun(1, x0=3))
# TypeError: fun() got multiple values for argument 'x0'
```

Comment: Thanks, for your help. I knew that something I am missing